# scala SocketServer

Tags: scala

what is the purpose of scala.tools.util.SocketServer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's part of the compiler, and not a part of the standard scala library. 
Its purpose is to implement the server communication for the [fsc](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/tools/fsc.html) (fast scala compiler). When you're compiling with `fsc` a server daemon process is started. This is done by starting up the `scala.tools.nsc.StandardCompilerServer`, which is a subclass of `scala.tools.util.SocketServer`. Once the fsc server is running, you avoid the overhead of having to start up a new JVM instance with every compilation that you do, which happens when you use `scalac` instead of `fsc` to compile your code.